# How to handle MongoDB ObjectIds in Play framework using Reactivemongo?

Tags: json, mongodb, playframework, reactivemongo

I have a basic model with a case class

```
case class Record( id: Option[String], 
                 data: Double,
                 user: String,
                 )

object RecordJsonFormats {
  import play.api.libs.json.Json

  implicit val recordFormat = Json.format[Record]
}
```

Field `user` is actually an `ObjectId` of other module also `id` is also an `ObjectId` yet then try to change `String` type to `BSONObjectId`  macros in `play.api.libs.json.Json` break... so both `user` and if saved with object `id` fields get saved as `String` not `ObjectId`.

What is the optimal way to operate with `ObjectIds` in Play framework?

- Maybe I should extend `play.api.libs.json.Json` with `BSONObjectId`?
- Maybe there is a way to link models and IDs are tracked automatically without a need to declare them in model?

Answer (score 3):

You can override the default type of _id. You just need to specify the type you want in the case class.

```
import java.util.UUID
import play.api.libs.json._

case class Record (_id: UUID = UUID.randomUUID())

object Record {
  implicit val entityFormat = Json.format[Record]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

MongoDB has a default *_id* field of type ObjectId, which uniquely identifies a document in a given collection. However, this *_id* typically does not have a semantic meaning in the context of the application domain. Therefore, a good practice is to introduce an additional *id* field as index of documents. This *id* can simply a Long number, no more or less.

Then, you can search documents by *id* easily, and do not care much about ObjectId.

This, https://github.com/luongbalinh/play-mongo/, is a sample project using Play 2.4.x and ReactiveMongo. Hopefully, it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

For those using Official Mongo Scala Driver and Play Framework 2.6+, Here's my solution: https://gist.github.com/ntbrock/556a1add78dc287b0cf7e0ce45c743c1

```scala
import org.mongodb.scala.bson.ObjectId
import play.api.libs.json._
import scala.util.Try

object ObjectIdFormatJsonMacro extends Format[ObjectId] {

  def writes(objectId: ObjectId): JsValue = JsString(objectId.toString)
  def reads(json: JsValue): JsResult[ObjectId] = json match {
    case JsString(x) => {
      val maybeOID: Try[ObjectId] = Try{new ObjectId(x)}
      if(maybeOID.isSuccess) JsSuccess(maybeOID.get) else {
        JsError("Expected ObjectId as JsString")
      }
    }
    case _ => JsError("Expected ObjectId as JsString")
  }
}
```

Use it like this in your business objects:

```
case class BusinessTime(_id: ObjectId = new ObjectId(), payRate: Double)

object BusinessTime {
  implicit val objectIdFormat = ObjectIdFormatJsonMacro
  implicit val businessTimeFormat = Json.format[BusinessTime]
}
```